# Find the magnitude of theta

Tags: geometry

I was given a problem telling me to find the magnitude of $\theta$.

[image: diagram]

I have been trying to reason it out using complements and such, but I haven't been able to get it. The diagram seems strange to me and I feel as if I am forgetting a trigonometric or geometric relationship that is the key to the solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the left leg of the $\theta$ angle is supposed to be normal to the hypotenuse of the 30-60-90 triangle, $\theta$ is also $30^\circ$.

Formally, you could argue that the intersection between the vertical line and the inclined plane just to the right of the $\theta$ in the figure has two vertical angles, which are opposite to, respectively, the one marked $30^\circ$ and the one marked $\theta$ in two right triangles.

Answer (score 1):

The post has been answered. This is just an explanation saying that the said diagram is not strange at all. It is a standard diagram found in a physics topic. see below for further explanations.

[image]

Comment: Very helpful diagram. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The angle $\theta$ will be $30^o$ irrespective of the weight or mass of the block because angle $\theta$ depends on the inclination of the plane with the horizontal.